# Equation for conditional values for variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to write an equation such that the answer depends on the value of the variable `missing`
if the value of `missing is 0` --  then `increment` needs to be `3`
if `missing is 1` - `increment 2` 
if `missing is 2` - `increment 1`

any ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: missing $+$ increment $=3$, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need an equation for relate the quantities `missing` and `increment` based only in those three 'rules'. To do this, you can plot the points in a plane by taking `missing` as the $x$ axis and `increment` as the $y$ axis, and then interpolate the points by a polynomial.
[image]
As in @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг comment, the simplest relation is the linear equation `increment`$=3-$`missing`.